# Detach ItemTouchHelper from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have a `RecyclerView` with a working `ItemTouchHelper`. Everything works great, but I am wondering if there is a way I can detach the `ItemTouchHelper` from the `RecyclerView` without re-creating the list?  For fun, this is the code I'm using to attach:

```
ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)
{
    ...
};
mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mPasswordList);
```

Ideally, I'd like to check a preference in say `onResume()` of the Activity this `RecyclerView` lives in and detach the `ItemTouchHelper` based on that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My original motivation for this was to allow the user the ability to disable swipe actions on list items if they so choose. I assumed the way to do this was to detach the `ItemTouchHelper` from the `RecyclerView`.  I have now found the `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` has the following method available to override:

```
@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled()
{
    return mSwipable;
}
```

So, returning the correct state here effectively turns off the swipe handling. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: This works perfect for me, i can set mSwipable to true or false depends the case thanks alot!

Answer (score 38):

You can detach the ItemTouchHelper from the RecyclerView by setting recyclerview to null:

```
mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null);
```

Comment: Nice trick. But, beware of this limitation : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37092256 Google claims they fix the bug. However, at the time for this comment being written, the fix isn't released to public yet.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng, I've checked Android docs, [they say](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper#attachToRecyclerView(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView)) that `mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null)` can be used for detaching.

Answer (score 1):

For me, to disable the entire `ItemTouchHelper` that attached to the `RecyclerView` just set it to `null`

```
mItemTouchHelper = null;
```

And to re-enable, set it to its value

```
mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
```